# Create database seeder with same random value in a table row with Laravel database seeder

Tags: database, laravel, faker

I am trying to create a table and populate the table with the following fields with the help of database seeder:

- option a
- option b
- option c
- option d
- correct option

First four fields will be assigned random word, and the last field 'correct option' will contain any one of the first four.
I could not find any solution to do it with Laravel database seeder. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you post your existing codes for this seeder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

use faker random element function in your factory or seeder.

```php
$optionA = $faker->word;
$optionB = $faker->word;
$optionC = $faker->word;
$optionD = $faker->word;

return [
        'option_a' => $optionA,
        'option_b' => $optionB,
        'option_c' => $optionC,
        'option_d' => $optionD,
        'correct_option'   => $faker->randomElement([$optionA,$optionB,$optionC,$optionD]),
];
```

Comment: This is the exact answer what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a factory and use Faker](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#writing-factories) to generate the random words you're after

Comment: This is not the solution according to the question. Please check the question again.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ideal use case for JSON columns (both for questions and answers).  For instance, you might decide to have multiple valid answers to a single multiple choice question.

In your migration:

```php
// create_questions_table.php
...
$table->json('choices')->default(new Expression('(JSON_ARRAY())'));
$table->json('answer')->default(new Expression('(JSON_ARRAY())'));
```

From https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#column-modifiers:

> Using an Expression instance will prevent wrapping the value in quotes and allow you to use database specific functions. One situation where this is particularly useful is when you need to assign default values to JSON columns.

Then create a factory:

```php
// QuestionFactory.php
$factory->define(Location::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $choices = $faker->words(4);
    $answer = [ $choices[rand(1,4)] ];

    return [
        'choices' => $choices,
        'answer' => $answer,
    ];
});
```

Using the Faker library included in Laravel, we can pick 4 words and randomly assign one of them to be the answer.